# How can I get the browser viewport size and use that to align my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, size, viewport

I am new to webdesign and I am wondering about the website size specially for a One Page Scroll Site. Sometimes I see some 'jumbotron' images with perfect height and width alignment to my browser size.Browser sizes can differ from one to another because of the browser ad-dons or extensions. So How can we get the users browser view port size and use that to align my website. I need a good explanation about all the things regarding the website sizes. Sorry for my poor English. If you wish, please provide the tutorial links that will help me also. Thank you

Comment: [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth) and [window.innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerHeight) should give you a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing this in the head of your page will help you.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have made your website already. If you have not I suggest using Bootstrap Grid System. That will align your website on all screen sizes.